# What is the characteristic of the module over Jacobson semisimple ring？

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, homological-algebra

We know a ring R is semisimple ring iff every module over R is semisimple，a ring R is von-Neumann regular ring iff every module over R is flat，What about the Jacobson semisimple ring？

Answer (score 3):

An alternative phrasing to Bugs's answer is as follows:

A ring $R$ is Jacobson semisimple if and only if the only element which annihilates every
simple $R$-module is the zero element.

In my experience (which is largely in the commutative case, or even finite type algebras over a field; in this latter case Jacobson semisimple coincides with reduced), this point of view on Jacobson semisimple rings is one that comes up frequently in arguments.

Comment: What does reduced mean?  The 2-adics are a local domain, so have no nilpotent elements, but it is not Jacobson semisimple.

Comment: Dear Jack, Yes, you are right, and I blundered.  I should have said 
"in the case of finite type algebras over a field", and I will make this correction now!

Answer (score 1):

[Mighty Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprimitive_ring) to the rescue!! Seriously I dont think you can say anything better than a semisimple faithful module exists...

What is the cause of your curiosity?

Having said that, I can think of a cute reformulation that makes it clear that the property is Morita-invariant:
for any projective $P$, the hom-space $Hom (P, \oplus_i S_i)$ is a faithful $End (P)$-module where the sum is taken over non-isomorphic simples in the category.

Comment: I think this kind of property is interesting,so I want to find more examples.Why the Jacobson semisimple ring is not like the semisimple ring?

Comment: Because it is not artinian, in general...

Comment:  Von-Neumann regular ring is also not artinian in general,but it has this kind of property. 

Comment: I am at a total loss what you mean...

Comment: “a ring R is von-Neumann regular ring iff every module over R is flat”，but Von-Neumann regular ring is also not artinian in general，so nonartin is not the reason. 